# getting max value from each column of the csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, python-3.x, generator

Would anybody help me to solve the following problem. I have tried it on my own and I have attached the solution also. I have used 2-d list, but I want a different solution without 2-d list, which should be more pythonic.

pl suggest me any of you have any other way of doing this.

Q)  Consider Share prices for a N number of companies given for each month since year 1990 in a CSV file.  Format of the file is as below with first line as header.

Year,Month,Company A, Company B,Company C, .............Company N

1990, Jan, 10, 15, 20, , ..........,50

1990, Feb, 10, 15, 20, , ..........,50

.

.

.

.

2013, Sep, 50, 10, 15............500

The solution should be in this format.
a) List for each Company year and month in which the share price was highest.

**Here is my answer using 2-d list.**

```
def generate_list(file_path):
    '''
        return list of list's containing file data.'''

    data_list=None   #local variable    
    try:
        file_obj = open(file_path,'r')
        try:
            gen = (line.split(',') for line in file_obj)  #generator, to generate one line each time until EOF (End of File)
            for j,line in enumerate(gen):
                if not data_list:
                    #if dl is None then create list containing n empty lists, where n will be number of columns.
                    data_list = [[] for i in range(len(line))]
                    if line[-1].find('\n'):
                        line[-1] = line[-1][:-1] #to remove last list element's '\n' character

                #loop to convert numbers from string to float, and leave others as strings only
                for i,l in enumerate(line):
                    if i >=2 and j >= 1:
                        data_list[i].append(float(l))
                    else:            
                        data_list[i].append(l)
        except IOError, io_except:
            print io_except
        finally:
            file_obj.close()
    except IOError, io_exception:
        print io_exception

    return data_list

def generate_result(file_path):
    '''
        return list of tuples containing (max price, year, month,
company name).
    '''
    data_list = generate_list(file_path)
    re=[]   #list to store results in tuple formet as follow [(max_price, year, month, company_name), ....]
    if data_list:
        for i,d in enumerate(data_list):
            if i >= 2:
                m = max(data_list[i][1:])      #max_price for the company
                idx = data_list[i].index(m)    #getting index of max_price in the list
                yr = data_list[0][idx]          #getting year by using index of max_price in list
                mon = data_list[1][idx]        #getting month by using index of max_price in list
                com = data_list[i][0]          #getting company_name
                re.append((m,yr,mon,com))
        return re


if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_path = 'C:/Document and Settings/RajeshT/Desktop/nothing/imp/New Folder/tst.csv'
    re = generate_result(file_path)
    print 'result ', re
```

`I have tried to solve it with generator also, but in that case it was giving result for only one company i.e. only one column.`

```
p = 'filepath.csv'

f = open(p,'r')
head = f.readline()
gen = ((float(line.split(',')[n]), line.split(',',2)[0:2], head.split(',')[n]) for n in range(2,len(head.split(','))) for i,line in enumerate(f))
x = max((i for i in gen),key=lambda x:x[0])
print x
```

you can take the below provided input data which is in csv format..

```
year,month,company 1,company 2,company 3,company 4,company 5
1990,jan,201,245,243,179,133
1990,feb,228,123,124,121,180
1990,march,63,13,158,88,79
1990,april,234,68,187,67,135
1990,may,109,128,46,185,236
1990,june,53,36,202,73,210
1990,july,194,38,48,207,72
1990,august,147,116,149,93,114
1990,september,51,215,15,38,46
1990,october,16,200,115,205,118
1990,november,241,86,58,183,100
1990,december,175,97,143,77,84
1991,jan,190,68,236,202,19
1991,feb,39,209,133,221,161
1991,march,246,81,38,100,122
1991,april,37,137,106,138,26
1991,may,147,48,182,235,47
1991,june,57,20,156,38,245
1991,july,165,153,145,70,157
1991,august,154,16,162,32,21
1991,september,64,160,55,220,138
1991,october,162,72,162,222,179
1991,november,215,207,37,176,30
1991,december,106,153,31,247,69
```

expected output is following.

```
[(246.0, '1991', 'march', 'company 1'),
 (245.0, '1990', 'jan', 'company 2'),
 (243.0,   '1990', 'jan', 'company 3'),
 (247.0, '1991', 'december', 'company 4'),
 (245.0, '1991', 'june', 'company 5')]
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Is numpy or pandas an option?

Comment: whatever you think is more pythonic and with maximum use of standard library functions only.. pl no third party...

Comment: OK, pandas and numpy are libraries you have to import, so I guess you would call that third party, but they are perfect for this kind of application. But you can do this with standard approaches as well...

Comment: It is bcz they don't come with standard libraries.. that's why.. Bt if you have more than one approach for the problem, you are welcome... :)

Comment: Can you post some actual sample data and expected output?

Comment: What's the motivation for using a generator here? in order to generate the first value (i.e. the max for the first company), you must read the entire file (because the fie is read row-by-row), and either store it in full in memery (for processing of the other companies), or process the other companies while reading. Either way, you must do the full work before finding the first result, thus gaining nothing by providing a generator over the results.

Comment: @hcwhsa I have provided the sample input and output... as u asked..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `collections.OrderedDict` and `collections.namedtuple`:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict, namedtuple

with open('abc1') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    tup = namedtuple('tup', ['price', 'year', 'month'])
    d = OrderedDict()
    names = next(reader)[2:]
    for name in names:
        #initialize the dict
        d[name] = tup(0, 'year', 'month')
    for row in reader:
        year, month = row[:2]         # Use year, month, *prices = row in py3.x
        for name, price in zip(names, map(int, row[2:])): # map(int, prices) py3.x
            if d[name].price < price:
                d[name] = tup(price, year, month)
print d
```

**Output:**

```
OrderedDict([
('company 1', tup(price=246, year='1991', month='march')),
('company 2', tup(price=245, year='1990', month='jan')),
('company 3', tup(price=243, year='1990', month='jan')),
('company 4', tup(price=247, year='1991', month='december')),
('company 5', tup(price=245, year='1991', month='june'))])
```

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't entirely sure how you wanted to output so for now I just have it print the output to screen.

```
import os
import csv
import codecs


## Import data  !!!!!!!!!!!! CHANGE TO APPROPRIATE PATH !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
filename= os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/PYTHON/StackTest/tailor_raj/Workbook1.csv")

## Get useable data
data = [row for row in csv.reader(codecs.open(filename, 'rb', encoding="utf_8"))]

## Find Number of rows
row_count= (sum(1 for row in data)) -1

## Find Number of columns
    ## Since this cannot be explicitly done, I set it to run through the columns on one row until it fails.
    ## Failure is caught by try/except so the program does not crash
columns_found = False
column_try =1
while columns_found == False:
    column_try +=1
    try:
        identify_column = data[0][column_try]
    except:
        columns_found=True
## Set column count to discoverd column count (1 before it failed)
column_count=column_try-1

## Set which company we are checking (start with the first company listed. Since it starts at 0 the first company is at 2 not 3)
companyIndex = 2

#This will keep all the company bests as single rows of text. I was not sure how you wanted to output them.
companyBest=[]

## Set loop to go through each company
while companyIndex <= (column_count):

    ## For each new company reset the rowIndex and highestShare
    rowIndex=1
    highestShare=rowIndex
    
    ## Set loop to go through each row
    while rowIndex <=row_count:
        ## Test if data point is above or equal to current max
        ## Currently set to use the most recent high point
        if int(data[highestShare][companyIndex]) <= int(data[rowIndex][companyIndex]):
            highestShare=rowIndex
            
        ## Move on to next row
        rowIndex+=1
        
    ## Company best = Company Name + year + month + value
    companyBest.append(str(data[0][companyIndex])+": "+str(data[highestShare][0]) +", "+str(data[highestShare][1])+", "+str(data[highestShare][companyIndex]))

    ## Move on to next company
    companyIndex +=1

for item in companyBest:
    print item
```

Be sure to change your filename path one more appropriate.

Output is currently displayed like this:

> Company A: 1990, Nov, 1985
>
> Company B: 1990, May, 52873
>
> Company C: 1990, May, 3658
>
> Company D: 1990, Nov, 156498
>
> Company E: 1990, Jul, 987

Comment: Thanks for your try.. I already done the longer way... But I wanted to do it using only generator (if it is possible) and in minimum lines of code.. i.e. in more pythonic way. :)

Comment: Ahh my fault. I just saw you tried a generator, and didn't realize you wanted a generator as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

No generator unfortunately but small code size, especially in Python 3:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from csv import reader

with open('test.csv') as f:
    year, month, *data = zip(*reader(f))

for pricelist in data:
    name = pricelist[0]
    prices = map(int, pricelist[1:])
    i, price = max(enumerate(prices), key=itemgetter(1))
    print(name, price, year[i+1], month[i+1])
```

In Python 2.X you can do the same thing but slightly more clumsy, using the following (and the different print statement):

```
with open('test.csv') as f:
    columns = zip(*reader(f))
    year, month = columns[:2]
    data = columns[2:]
```

---

Okay I came up with some gruesome generators! Also it makes use of lexicographic tuple comparison and `reduce` to compare consecutive lines:

```
from functools import reduce  # only in Python 3
import csv

def group(year, month, *prices):
    return ((int(p), year, month) for p in prices)

def compare(a, b):
    return map(max, zip(a, group(*b)))

def run(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        r = csv.reader(f)
        names = next(r)[2:]
        return zip(names, reduce(compare, r, group(*next(r))))

list(run('test.csv'))
```

Comment: Can someone please write the test cases for this problem