# list comprehension to create list and for no-data value feed default value

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

Would anybody tell me how to create a list using list comprehension, having default values for no-data values like the below problem.

I have a triangular data set, which I want to feed to 2-D list using list comprehension.
I want to feed 0's instead of no-data values.

input form...

```
   3
  7 4
 2 4 6
8 5 9 3
```

output form.

```
3 0 0 0
7 4 0 0 
2 4 6 0
8 5 9 3
```

Can anybody help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself yet? Why does it *have* to be a list comprehension? Do you know the maximum length of a row up front?

Comment: No.. I dont know the max lenght of list... I have tried bt It seems that there is no way using only list comprehension.. or if there is a way it will be very complex... :)

Comment: You will *have* to loop at least twice then; once to get the length. hcwhsa's answer below does loop twice, hidden in the `*` parameter expansions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.izip_longest`:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> strs = """   3                             
  7 4
 2 4 6
8 5 9 3"""
>>> lis = [s.split() for s in strs.splitlines()]
>>> zip(*(izip_longest(*lis, fillvalue='0')))
[('3', '0', '0', '0'),
 ('7', '4', '0', '0'),
 ('2', '4', '6', '0'),
 ('8', '5', '9', '3')]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419154/getting-max-value-from-each-column-of-the-csv-file

Comment: @tailor_raj Please don't post unrelated comments.

Comment: NO.. it is a good question, and I have solved that also.. but I was trying to get efficient way of doing that.. because I am beginner...

Comment: @tailor_raj I am not saying that it is bad question. But that question is not related to this question anyhow, so you should not post comments like that. Read: [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)