# Convert namedtuple to list in python and generate CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19726081/1182021

```
OrderedDict([
('company 1', tup(price=246, year='1991', month='march')),
('company 2', tup(price=245, year='1990', month='jan')),
('company 3', tup(price=243, year='1990', month='jan')),
('company 4', tup(price=247, year='1991', month='december')),
('company 5', tup(price=245, year='1991', month='june'))])
```

How to export this data in csv format like this:

```
Company Name , Price , Year , Month
Company 1    , 246   , 1991 , march
Company 2    , 245   , 1990 , jan
```

I tried creating a csv using `import csv` like this (**ALL IN SAME ROW**):

```
myfile = open(csvfile, 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(myfile , quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
wr.writerow(data_list)
```

**EDIT 1**

where `data_list` is the OrderedDict and I am getting all data incorrect format

```
Company-A | Filtered(Year='2013', Month='Dec', Price=0) Company-B   | Filtered(Year='2013', Month='Dec', Price=0) |     Company-C  |    Filtered(Year='2013', Month='Dec', Price=0) |   Company-D |     Filtered(Year='2013', Month='Dec', Price=0) Company-E |     Filtered(Year='2013', Month='Dec', Price=0)
```

**EDIT 2**

OK I converted OrderedDict to simple list by `data_list = OrderedDict.items()`

And as suggested by [mkrehili](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24839761/1182021) I have this as my export method:

```
def ExportData(csv_file, data_list):
    csv_file = open(csv_file, 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for company_name, company_data in data_list:
        wr.writerow([company_name] + list(company_data))
```

And I am getting this list now:

```
[('Company-A', Filtered(Year='2013', Month='Dec', Price=0)), ('Company-B', Filtered(Year='2013', Month='Dec', Price=0)), ('Company-C', Filtered(Year='2013', Month='Dec', Price=0)), ('Company-D', Filtered(Year='2013', Month='Dec', Price=0)), ('Company-E', Filtered(Year='2013', Month='Dec', Price=0))]
```

But when I am converting it in CSV the following is the output:

```
Company-A   2013    Dec 0
Company-B   2013    Dec 0
Company-C   2013    Dec 0
Company-D   2013    Dec 0
Company-E   2013    Dec 0
```

**EDIT 3**
Actually both the data are not coming same:

In OrderedDict its:

```
OrderedDict([
('company A', tup(price=246, year='1991', month='march')),
('company B', tup(price=245, year='1990', month='jan')),
('company C', tup(price=243, year='1990', month='jan')),
('company D', tup(price=247, year='1991', month='december')),
('company E', tup(price=245, year='1991', month='june'))])
```

But once I do `data_list = OrderedDict.items()` it gives me this data: Which is not in correct format:

```
[('Company-A', tup(price=0, year="2013", month='Dec')),
 ('Company-B', tup(price=0, year="2013", month='Dec')), 
 ('Company-C', tup(price=0, year="2013", month='Dec')), 
 ('Company-D', tup(price=0, year="2013", month='Dec')), 
 ('Company-E', tup(price=0, year="2013", month='Dec'))]
```

So majorly my issue is to create a simple list where i have list like this:

```
Company Name , Price , Year , Month
Company A    , 246   , 1991 , march
Company B    , 245   , 1990 , jan
......
......
```

**EDIT 4**

```
with open(csv_file, 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(('Company Name', 'Year', 'Month', 'Price'))
    w.writerows([(name, data.year, data.month, data.price) for   name, data in data_list])`
```

This is giving me right export, but after each line I am having an empty row, like this:

```
Company Name    Year    Month   Price

Company-A   2000    Mar 1000

Company-B   2007    Mar 986

Company-C   1993    Jun 995

Company-D   2002    Apr 999

Company-E   2008    Oct 997
```

Comment: Python CSV module is your friend: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo I have done an edit please review

Comment: You must call `writerow` on each row (key/value pair) separately...

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Can you please help me in converting this OrderedDict line wise comma saperated values

Comment: Following your 2nd edit, what actually is the problem? Is it the order of the fields in the output CSV? The output is consistent with the order of the `namedtuple` fields in your data.

Comment: @mhawke Please review I have done an edit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import csv
from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict

tup = namedtuple('tup', ['price', 'year', 'month'])
prices = OrderedDict([
    ('company A', tup(price=246, year='1991', month='march')),
    ('company B', tup(price=245, year='1990', month='jan')),
    ('company C', tup(price=243, year='1990', month='jan')),
    ('company D', tup(price=247, year='1991', month='december')),
    ('company E', tup(price=245, year='1991', month='june'))])

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(('Company Name', 'Price', 'Year', 'Month'))    # field header
    w.writerows([(name, data.price, data.year, data.month) for name, data in prices.items()])
```

Writes to output.csv:

```
Company Name,Price,Year,Month
company A,246,1991,march
company B,245,1990,jan
company C,243,1990,jan
company D,247,1991,december
company E,245,1991,june
```

Comment: Its always taking data of last namedlist for other fields

Comment: Edit 3 just confuses the issue. There is no way that `data_list = OrderedDict.items()` will convert your data as you say. Please clarify what data you are using... `namedtuple('Filtered', ['Year', 'Month', 'Price'])` or `namedtuple('tup', ['price', 'year', 'month'])`.

Comment: OOPS I am sorry its `tup` only, I was trying something in meanwhile. Correted

Comment: Forget about lists... I am just using this OrderedDict

Comment: @DjangoAnonymous : revised for `namedtuple('tup',...)`. Output is consistent with your requirements. Note that you won't be able to get the `csv` module to exactly generate the whitespace in your desired output because it will accept a single character delimiter only.

Comment: Everything is fine, just one issue that each row is followed by an extra row in between

Comment: Check my recent Edit 4

Comment: Your data keeps fluctuating and there is no way that the code in edit 4 can produce that output - `w = csv.writer(f)` will use the default `csv.execel` dialect which uses `,` as a delimiter, not tabs. The extra blank line might have something to do with `Dialect.lineterminator` - which dialect are you specifying?

Answer (score 1):

namedtuple is still iterable so treat it like such:

```
>>> tup = namedtuple('tup', ['price', 'year', 'month'])
>>> c = tup(price=246, year='1991', month='march')
>>> list(c)
[246, '1991', 'march']
>>> print(*c)
246 1991 march
```

So in your example (you didn't post complete code, which makes things harder):

```
for company_name, company_data in data_list.items():
    wr.writerow([company_name] + list(company_data))
```

Comment: But when it is giving me an ordered list, how I can able to loop over and check if it a `namedtuple` then id your thing. Basically I am looking for formatting in a way that I can export it to csv file. Please, I will appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Hey! I have done a check with what you said, But I still have an issue and added it as EDIT 2, please review.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that honors the question title (which mentions named tuples but not OrderedDict).

OrderedDict like in the other answers is probably a better approach but I am listing this just in case it is useful to others who might not need rows to be indexed.

I made a more generic Gitlab Snippet, [Name Tuple Demo: Saving a named tuple to csv](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1868266) which goes over a bit more on this subject.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import csv
from pathlib import Path


CompanyDetails = namedtuple(
    'CompanyDetails', ('company_name', 'price', 'year', 'month',)
)


def format_csv_header(header_fields):
    return tuple(
        header_field.replace("_", " ").title()
        for header_field in header_fields
    )


def write_contents_to_csv(contents, csv_file):
    with Path(csv_file).open('w') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        header = format_csv_header(contents._fields)
        rows = zip(*contents)
        all_rows = (header,) + (*rows,)
        writer.writerows(all_rows)


# Example: Row Indexed. Consider using OrderedDict here instead!
company_details = CompanyDetails(
    company_name=(
        'Company 1', 'Company 2', 'Company 3', 'Company 4', 'Company 5',
    ),
    price=(246, 245, 243, 247, 245,),
    year=('1991', '1990', '1990', '1991', '1991',),
    month=('march', 'jan', 'jan', 'december', 'june',)
)
write_contents_to_csv(company_details, '/tmp/company_details.csv')
```